# IE11 not working when using babel v7 SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-loader, babel-polyfill

I have recently updated babel to use babel 7. i managed to get it working with chrome. IE11 does not work and I am not sure how to fix it. I am using webpack 3. The line it is failing on is

`exports = module.exports = function (...args) {`

**here is my package.json**

```
{
    "name": "sample",
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "lint": "eslint src/",
        "lint:fix": "eslint src/ --fix",
        "start": "node src/server.js",
        "test": "node_modules/.bin/jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.5",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.15",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.7.2",
        "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.4",
        "audit": "0.0.6",
        "axios": "^0.18.1",
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "bootstrap-fileinput": "^4.5.2",
        "braces": "^2.3.2",
        "console-polyfill": "^0.3.0",
        "core-js": "^2.5.7",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
        "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
        "dompurify": "^1.0.10",
        "es5-shim": "^4.5.13",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
        "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.1",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "html-react-parser": "^0.4.7",
        "jquery": "^3.4.0",
        "jsx-to-string": "^1.4.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.11",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
        "npm": "^6.9.0",
        "npm-audit": "0.0.3",
        "postcss-cssnext": "^3.0.2",
        "postcss-import": "^11.1.0",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "pusher": "^2.2.0",
        "pusher-js": "^4.4.0",
        "react": "^16.8.4",
        "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
        "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
        "react-bootstrap-table": "^4.3.1",
        "react-bootstrap-table-next": "^0.1.15",
        "react-dates": "^17.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
        "react-dropzone": "^4.3.0",
        "react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
        "react-ga": "^2.5.7",
        "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
        "react-moment": "^0.8.4",
        "react-quill": "^1.3.3",
        "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
        "react-router": "^4.3.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
        "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
        "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
        "react-select": "^1.3.0",
        "react-sortable-tree": "^2.6.0",
        "react-stringify": "^1.0.0",
        "react-table": "^6.9.2",
        "react-tooltip": "^3.10.0",
        "react-vis": "^1.11.6",
        "react-websocket": "^2.0.1",
        "react-widgets": "^4.4.10",
        "redux": "^3.7.2",
        "redux-file-upload": "0.0.19",
        "redux-form": "^7.4.2",
        "redux-listeners": "^0.4.1",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
        "redux-title": "0.0.3",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.2",
        "single-spa": "^4.3.5",
        "single-spa-react": "^2.10.2",
        "socket.io": "^2.2.0",
        "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0",
        "sugarss": "^1.0.1",
        "supervisor": "^0.12.0",
        "url-search-params": "^0.10.2",
        "viz": "0.0.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.4.4",
        "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.4.4",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.4.4",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator": "^7.4.5",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.4.4",
        "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/register": "^7.4.4",
        "autoprefixer-loader": "^3.2.0",
        "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.16.0",
        "babel-jest": "^24.4.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.6.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
        "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
        "eslint": "^5.16.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
        "eslint-config-rallycoding": "^3.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-babel": "^5.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.2",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
        "expect": "^24.4.0",
        "fetch-mock": "^6.5.2",
        "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
        "jest": "latest",
        "jest-html-reporter": "^2.5.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.15",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
        "prettier": "1.11.1",
        "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
        "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
        "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
        "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.2",
        "riek": "^1.1.0",
        "sass": "^1.17.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
        "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.8",
        "webpack": "^3.12.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.5",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.2"
    }
}
```

**my webpack file**

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
//const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/index.js',
    ],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: __dirname + '/docs',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: "json-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.js[x]?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    presets: [ '@babel/preset-react' ],
                    plugins: [ '@babel/transform-runtime', '@babel/transform-regenerator' ]
                }
            },
             {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
                        'postcss-loader'
                    ]
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                use: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
            },
            {
                test: /\.png$/,
                use: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
            },
            {
                test: /\.jpg$/,
                use: 'file-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2) (\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
            },
            {
                test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'
            },
            {
                test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: 'file-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'
            }
        ]
    },
    node: {
        fs: 'empty'
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: __dirname + '/src/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html',
            inject: true
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'),
                'REACT_APP_GA_TRACKING_ID' : JSON.stringify('UA-101927425-1'),
                'VERSION': JSON.stringify('57')
            }
        }),
        new UglifyJsPlugin(),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: "jquery",
            $: "jquery",
            jquery: 'jquery'
        }),

        new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].bundle.css")
    ],
    devtool: 'source-map',
    externals: [],
};
```

**my babel file**

```
module.exports = function(api) {
    api.cache(true);

    const presets = [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env", {
                "targets": {
                    "browsers": ["> 0.25%, not dead"]
                },
                "modules": false,
                "debug":true,
                "useBuiltIns": 'entry'
            }
        ],
        ["@babel/preset-react"],
    ];
    const plugins = [
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
            {
                legacy: true
            }
        ],
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements",
        //"@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements"
    ];

    return {
        presets,
        plugins,
        "env": {
            "test": {
                "presets": [
                    [
                        "@babel/preset-env",
                        {
                            "targets": {
                                "node": "current"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried following https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill/. When in debug mode and run webpack I get a lot of `Import of @babel/polyfill was not found.` I am using `SPA` and my src index looks like

```
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'raf/polyfill';
import '../scripts/api';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { titleReducer, syncReduxAndTitle } from 'redux-title'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension/developmentOnly';
import App from '../App'
import reducers from '../reducers';
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css'; // ES6
import 'core-js/modules/es6.string.starts-with';

import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faSpinner, faPlus, faEdit, faTrashAlt } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

library.add(faSpinner);
library.add(faPlus);
library.add(faEdit);
library.add(faTrashAlt);

require("@babel/register");
require("@babel/polyfill");


const store = createStore(
        reducers,
        composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(promise))
        );
syncReduxAndTitle(store);

class SampleApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <App/>
            </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default SampleApp;
```

sample repo here https://github.com/shorif2000/babel_upgrade

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the same issue

Comment: no, i have a thread on github https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10227